# Unwanted space above Input-type File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form using bootstrap and have edited a few styles. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/359p5swa/1/).

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Logo</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" placeholder="Logo" autofocus="" required="" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required="" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.form-control {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

In the fiddle you can see that the address textarea is perfectly fine whereas the file input is attached to the bottom of the input field. How do I make it right? I have tried removing the padding, margins, setting line height to 0 but nothings makes a it different.

Comment: Remove `height` of `#logo`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vzghjayt/)

Comment: @Tushar I added a new rule `#logo { height: 0; }` it didn't work. (with min and max heights too)

Comment: Remove the padding from the #logo and add a height instead. #logo { padding: 0; height:40px; }

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Use `#logo { height: auto; }`.

Comment: @ThomasByy `height: 46px; padding: 0` makes it go to the top left and not in center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the `height` that is applied to `.form-control`. And as you've applied `padding` of `20px` vertical to the `.form-control` the file upload button is placed at 20px from the top of its container.

If you want to place the file upload button vertically center, apply `auto` height to the file input.

```
#logo {
    height: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vzghjayt/)

```css
#logo {
  height: auto;
}
.form-control {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Logo</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" placeholder="Logo" autofocus="" required="" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required="" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `<input name="logo" id="logo" placeholder="Logo" autofocus="" required="" class="form-control" type="file">` you are calling class "form-control" which gives the field `height:34px;` that makes the input field looks like that, you should add to your css `#logo{height:auto;}`

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: none;
}
#logo{
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Logo</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" placeholder="Logo" autofocus="" required="" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required="" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need of `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce padding

```
.form-control {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: none;
}
#logo{
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Logo</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" placeholder="Logo" autofocus="" required="" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required="" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/359p5swa/2/)